# How to count active Kafka consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, statistics, analytics

We're collecting some anonymised analytics to tack monthly active users with our current REST-based solution and considering migrating to Apache Kafka. Is it possible to have some stats on the consumers (count, connections, messages delivered)? If yes, is it GDPR-friendly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka doesn't really provide this out-of-the-box.

None of these have identifiable data attached to them

- TCP connections can be counted via standard network tools.
- Message *bytes delivered* requires external JMX metric aggregation.
- Message count is not available without custom code (since consumers can optionally not track offsets at all, or they can rewind themselves)

To count *active* consumers, you'll need to fetch all consumer *groups*, then iterate consumers of the groups.